# Jquery Datatables - How to search if either the user pressed Enter or search box is out of focus?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to configure datatables in our search function to do the following:
Only search when they do one of the following:

- click enter
- the field loses focus
- no user input for 3 or 4 seconds

Right now our search box is filtering as soon as someone starts typing.
this is the code I have right now

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#personnel-list-table_filter input').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true
    });

    $('#personnel-list-table_filter input').unbind();
    $('#personnel-list-table_filter input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            oTable.fnFilter(this.value);   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solid `fnSetFilteringDelay` plugin you can use to set delays for the filtering: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnSetFilteringDelay

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnSetFilteringDelay = function(oSettings, iDelay) {
    var _that = this;
 
    if (iDelay === undefined) {
        iDelay = 250;
    }
 
    this.each(function(i) {
        if (typeof _that.fnSettings().aanFeatures.f !== 'undefined') {
            $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
            
            var oTimerId = null,
                sPreviousSearch = null,
                anControl = $('input', _that.fnSettings().aanFeatures.f);
     
            anControl.unbind('keyup search input').on('keyup search input', function() {
                if (sPreviousSearch === null || sPreviousSearch != anControl.val()) {
                    window.clearTimeout(oTimerId);
                    sPreviousSearch = anControl.val();
                    oTimerId = window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
                        _that.fnFilter(anControl.val());
                    }, iDelay);
                }
            });

            return this;
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

The default is 250 millisecond but you can change it to your liking. After you put this plugin right after your original DataTables script, you should be able to use it like this:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#personnel-list-table').dataTable({
        ...
    }).fnSetFilteringDelay(1000);  // Set the delay to 1s
});
```